# Is there a way to make the active object semi-transparent in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

I know how to make my object semi-transparent in Object Mode with Solid Viewport Shading as well as how to disable "Limit selection to visible" in Edit Mode, but I have not yet figured out if it is possible to set the active selected object to appear semi-transparent in Sculpt Mode. Does anyone know if this can be done and if so, how?

Alternatively, I would accept a solution where the inactive selections appear transparent, similar to how transparency functions in ZBrush. In the image below, the red object is the active selection that is being edited.

[image]

Comment: If your material has a transparent component, you can use "Viewport Alpha" under Settings in the Material tab of the Properties window.  Set it to something like "Alpha Blend".  It will indeed show up with a sort of transparency in Sculpt mode when in Material view (although it might be hard to see for sculpting - I suggest adding only a tiny amount of transparency via a mix shader).

Comment: I can think of only adding Transparent shader to material and sculpting while in Material shading mode (in material settings in the Properties editor set Viewport Alpha to any other option other than Opaque). Other than that could you show some reference images of transparency you're searching for?

Comment: Thanks guys. I experimented with your suggestions and posted a workable solution. Hopefully there is something better, but this will work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "a solution" is to

- Assign a new material to the active object.
- Add a Transparent BSDF to the Diffuse BSDF via a Mix Shader and tweak
  the Mix Shader's Fac value.
- Go to the Material tab>Settings>Viewport Alpha and set it to Alpha
  Blend.
- Go to the Object tab>Display and enable X-Ray.
- Go to Sculpt Mode and set the Viewport Shading to Material.

[image]

The white object is the active object that is being sculpted.

Note: You will have to manually assign this material to the active object and unassign it from the inactive objects as part of your workflow, in addition to enabling X-ray for the active object and disabling X-ray from the inactive object. An add-on that could do this would be very nice.